# How to get the selected text inside google docs document into a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a chrome extension where if you select a text from anywhere, and open the chrome extension, it should paste the selected text inside the input element of the extension.

But when I try to select the text in google docs, it doesn't appear on the input element, nor does it shows on the console.

Here is my code

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var text = "";
  var activeEl = document.activeElement;
  var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
  if (
    activeElTagName == "textarea" ||
    (activeElTagName == "input" &&
      /^(?:text|search|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type) &&
      typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
  ) {
    text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return text;
}

async function scriptSelectionText(tabId) {
  console.log("tabId", tabId);
  const data = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabId },
    function: getSelectedText,
  });
  return data[0]?.result;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible*, as Google Docs does not add the text (selected or not) to the browser DOM, but uses a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) to render the text.

*) Of course, technically, there are options - but they are probably complex and not robust: OCR the canvas or reverse engineer Google Docs and try to find the selected text in some javascript object.

Comment: Then, how does grammarly do it.

Comment: don't know about that specifically - but I'd guess they went through the pain of one of the two mentioned methods: "OCR" or "reverse engineer and read from js object"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your method works because it embeds the characters in the script tag.

[image]